# How to call a javascript external src with another javascript src?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 files that should be connected.

**file.php** and **page.html**

**file.php** contain this code below:

```
 document.writeln('< script src="https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js">
  googletag.pubads().definePassback('/11322282/48fashion.com//300x250', [300, 250]).set("page_url","http://48fashion.com/").display();
< /script>');
```

**page.html**  contain this code below:

```
< html > <br>
&nbsp;&nbsp; < head>  <br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;< script  src="file.php"  type="text/javascript" > < /script> 
<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;< /head> 


< body> <br>

< /body> <br>

< /html>
```

---

Now when I refresh the **page.html** I received this error message **"Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"**

No, I see that loading a js src with another js src is not working. How make it work?

Comment: You try to insert using `document.writeln` javascript code but you don't wrap it inside `<script>..</script>` tags

Comment: I updated the code, please check again.

Comment: But that's not valid code, you don't close `script` tag. Now, what is the real code you are using? We cannot help you to catch synthax error if you just post some random code. And see Samir's answer, because this is a valid point, you have mismatching quotes

Comment: I'm sorry about that, I though it was added but when I updated stack overflow filtered it. I didn't noticed that. That should have a closing tag.

Comment: BUT that's still not the code you are using or it is still wrong because a `script` with `src` attribute just ignores its content. Anyway, you have fixed your issue... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
document.writeln('< script src="https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js"> googletag.pubads().definePassback("/11322282/48fashion.com//300x250", [300, 250]).set("page_url","http://48fashion.com/").display(); < /script>');
```

you had used wrong quote on definePassBack

Answer (score 2):

sorry i can't make comment so here its, just change the single quote to double quote after definePasspack

Comment: That could be an answer... ;)

Comment: ok again change the single quote in definePassback("/11322282/48fashion.com//300x250", to double quote and add </script> of end of statement.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should escape the single or the double quotes within the write line.

```
document.writeln(
        '<script src="https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js">
            googletag.pubads().definePassback(\'/11322282/48fashion.com//300x250\',
                [300, 250]).set("page_url","http://48fashion.com/").display();
        </script>');
```

Or put "/11322282/48fashion.com//300x250" between double quotes.

Comment: PHP extension works fine even code is javascript and correct that's the only code I produced in php file.